# histogram /ggplot with x and y and True of False

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram with the x axis as age and y axis as 0 or 1 (true or false)

```
person = c(1:50)
age = sample(1:5,50,replace=T) 
drunk = sample(0:1,50,replace=T)
df = data.frame(person,age,drunk)

#plots that I tried:
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = drunk)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

hist(df$age)

barplot(df$drunk, names.arg=df$age)
```

These plots are not working for me. What I'm trying to get is: the X axis should look like 50 numbers ranging from 1-5 and the Y axis should be either 0 or 1 (True or False)

```
df$drunk <- as.character(df$drunk)
df$drunk[df$drunk == "0"] <- "False"
df$drunk[df$drunk == "1"] <- "True"
```

I tried using the code above to make a plot with it, but it's not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoFhQ.png for example. Each Person has a random age in the plot and its shown if he is/was drunk (0 - 1 or true / false)

Comment: This part is not clear to me: "the X axis should look like 50 numbers ranging from 1-5".  Can you draw an image by hand and upload it?

Comment: @KotaMori I added a image and a discription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. change the x in your `aes` to `person`
2. add `factor(drunk)` to your y in `aes`
3. add `scale_y_discrete` to label the y axis with TRUE and FALSE instead of 1 and 0.
4. add `scale_x_discrete` to change the `person` tick label to the corresponding `age` using a helper function in `label`, and setting the limits as the range of the `person` variable in `df`.

   ```
   ggplot(df, aes(x = person, y = factor(drunk))) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      labs(x = "Age", y = "Drunk") +
      scale_y_discrete(labels = c("FALSE","TRUE")) +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(min(df$person), max(df$person)), labels = function(x) df[df$person == x,]$age)
   ```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks! how should one handle hundreds of rows in person / age?

Comment: This should work for any number of rows in `df`, provided they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=person,y=age,fill=factor(drunk))) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: It does work, but that's not what im looking for. The age should be the x axis and the drunk (0 or 1) should be the y axis. I tried editing the code a bit to ggplot(df,aes(x=age,y=drunk,fill=drunk)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') , but that's not working either